# Adicionar mais de um dropdown na navbar

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Como eu poderia adicionar mais elementos dropdowns na navbar do meu código? Tentei copiar o `button` e colar logo abaixo em meu código, porém a barra de navegação é replicada abaixo, só quero mais opções ao lado do item “Arquivo”.

Segue o código:

```
</head>
    <body>
         <div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Arquivo
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Novo</a>
      <a href="#">Abrir</a>
        <a href="#">Salvar</a>
        <div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Arquivo
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
         <textarea rows="35" cols="142">
        </textarea>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Qual versão do Bootstrap vc está usando??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que a tag `<div class="navbar">` está duplicada no seu código!

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
    <body>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Arquivo
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <button class="dropbtn">Arquivo
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Novo</a>
          <a href="#">Abrir</a>
          <a href="#">Salvar</a>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <textarea rows="35" cols="142">
    </textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]